# angularJs, I'm not succeeding set view refresh after data get from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've searched a lot before answer this question and couldn'y find any solution working for me.

I've started studying angular and I've been able to create a simple page with an ng-repeat that iter an object.

The next step I want to achieve is to update this object from an AJAX call to an API. The problem is that I'm not able to do this.
It seems to me that the problem is the function inside the controller: is not able to edit an attribute of the same controller:

```
app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', 'ajaxFactory',
    function($http, ajaxFactory) {
        this.products = products;

        this.getProducts = function() {
            /* this works and empty the object AND the view on the click */
            this.products = [];

            ajaxFactory.getFamily2().then(function(data) {
                /*
                 * this DOES NOT works, DOES NOT empty the object NOR the
                 * view on the click
                 */
                /*
                 * i'm sure the AJAX call is working, i can see the result
                 * and also alert his content
                 */
                this.products = data;
            });

        };
    } ]);
```

Thanks in advance

FULL CODE:
Html:

```
<div ng-app="catalogo">
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <!--  *** Store Header ***  -->
    <header class="text-center">
        <h3>– an Angular catalogue –</h3>
    </header>

    <!--  *** Products Container ***  -->
    <div class="container" ng-controller="TotalPriceController as total">
        <div class="row">
            <!--  Product Container  -->
            <div class="col col-xs-4"
                ng-repeat="(key,product) in store.products"
                ng-class="{ hero: key%2 === 0 }">
                <div class="row">
                    <product-title></product-title>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Image Gallery  -->
                    <product-gallery></product-gallery>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Product Tabs  -->
                    <product-calculate></product-calculate>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Product Tabs  -->
                    <product-tabs></product-tabs>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button ng-click="store.getProducts()">Kliq Here!</button>
            <product-total></product-total>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('catalogo', [ 'store-directives' ]);

app.factory('ajaxFactory', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getFamily2 = function() {
        return $http.get("http://apigility-ds.gsanet.it/rpc").then(
                function(result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
    }
    return factory;
});

app.controller('TotalPriceController', function() {
    this.totalPrice = 0;

    this.calculateTotalPrice = function() {
        this.totalPrice = 0;
        for ( var x in products) {
            var product = products[x];
            if (typeof (product.num) !== 'undefined') {
                this.totalPrice += (product.price * product.num);
            }
        }
    };
});

app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', 'ajaxFactory',
        function($http, ajaxFactory) {
            this.products = products;

            this.getProducts = function() {
                this.products = [];

                ajaxFactory.getFamily2().then(function(data) {
                    this.products = data;
                });

            };
        } ]);

app.controller('ReviewController', function() {
    this.review = {};

    this.addReview = function(product) {
        product.reviews.push(this.review);
        this.review = {};
    };
});

var products = [ {
    name : 'Ballons',
    price : 7.99,
    description : "A lot of colored ballons",
    images : [ "../img/balloons.jpg", "../img/balloons2.jpg" ],
    specs : {
        number : 10,
        color : 'various'
    },
    reviews : []
}, {
    name : 'Cards',
    price : 3.99,
    description : "wonderful set of cards.",
    images : [ "../img/cards.jpg", "../img/cards2.jpg" ],
    specs : {
        type : 'poker deck',
        cards : 52
    },
    reviews : []
}, {
    name : 'Watch',
    price : 159.99,
    description : "An awesome watch, make you so cool.",
    images : [ "../img/watchmaker.jpg", "../img/watchmaker2.jpg" ],
    specs : {
        color : 'black',
        year : '2014',
        brand : 'SWATCH'
    },
    reviews : []
} ];
```

})();

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does your AjaxFactory return the right data?

Comment: Looks like a simple matter of JavaScript changing the "this" value in different functions. Try storing `this` in a variable like `var self = this`, and then set `self.products`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having invalid reference to `this.products` from closure(It doesn't refere to `this.products` declared outside the `getProducts` function). You can correct it like this

```
app.controller('StoreController', [ '$http', 'ajaxFactory',
    function($http, ajaxFactory) {
        var controller = this;
        controller.products = products;

        controller.getProducts = function() {
            /* this works and empty the object AND the view on the click */
            controller.products = [];

            ajaxFactory.getFamily2().then(function(data) {
                /*
                 * this DOES NOT works, DOES NOT empty the object NOR the
                 * view on the click
                 */
                /*
                 * i'm sure the AJAX call is working, i can see the result
                 * and also alert his content
                 */
                controller.products = data;
            });

        };
    } ]);
```

Between you can also have a look on [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to make your code more robust and easier to test.